# How do I check Flutterflow inputs for duplicates in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

I want to add extra validation when the user enters their username. Duplicates can currently be created per user. In other words, every user could have the same username. However, I want each user to have a unique name and there are no duplicates.

Currently I've looked everywhere in Flutterflow and Firebase. Unfortunately nothing suitable was found.

Comment: Have you tried to perform a query and check if a username already exists before letting a user create an account?